# Querying Streams, serial input Swi prolog

Tags: arduino, prolog, swi-prolog

I have an arduino set up in a simple manner that read a potentiometer and writes the output to the serial connection.

```
void setup() {
 // initialize serial communication
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 // read the value of A0, divide by 4 and
 // send it as a byte over the serial connection
 Serial.write(analogRead(A0) / 4);
 delay(20);
}
```

I would like to have a prolog program that monitors this stream in the background. I would like it to log certain events but also for me to query the stream at any time.

I dont really know where to begin to set this up. How do I actually read a stream, and then how do I have two process/threads (Not sure what to call them). Where one process monitors the stream and a second process runs the top level so I can query a dynamic database?

I imagine something like:

```
:-dynamic currentvalue/1.

startthread1 :-
 loop.

loop :- read_serial(X),
    check(X),
    retractall(currentvalue(_)),
    assertz(currentvalue(X)),
    loop.

check(X):-
  X>100,
  get_time(Time),
  write_file(Time,X).
check(_).
```

*I omit the def of write_file

I think I would then query:

```
?- thread_create(startthread1, Id, [alias(serial_mon)]).
```

And then I should still  have the top level available for me to query `currentvalue/1' when I want to ?

Will this work? How do I define `read_serial/1`. ? Also how would I stop the thread which I named `serial_mon` ?

***update***

I have changed the loop code to the following:

```
void loop() {
 // read the value of A0, divide by 4 and
 // send it as a byte over the serial connection
 Serial.print(analogRead(A0) / 4);
 Serial.print('.');
 delay(100);
}
```

If I look at the serial monitor I now get output like this:

`205.205.205.205. etc`

Which I think I should be able to read by using read/2?

If my prolog code is simply:

```
go(File):-
 open(File,read,Stream,[]),
 read(Stream,X),
 writeln(X),
 close(Stream).
```

And I query :

```
?-go('/dev/ttyACM0').
```

I get no output. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic idea is OK. However, there are a few very important points you need to think about.

## Reading from a stream

This is the easier part: Regarding "how do I actually read a stream", there are several options, and they are the ones you already know from single-threaded applications. The cleanest one is to use `library(pio)` by Ulrich Neumerkel, and simply write a DCG that transparently reads from a stream. Another good option is to simply use `read/1` or `read/2` to read a **Prolog term** from a stream. Of course, the latter option requires the sensor to actually emit Prolog terms that can be automatically processed by these predicates, while the former option is more flexible.

You can also use **network sockets** and set up a simple web-based interface for communication.  For example, check out [JSON libraries](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=httpjson) for a simple and portable format. In summary, there is no shortage of options to handle this.

Personally, I recommend staying to **Prolog syntax** for such exchanges, simply because you can more conveniently handle the data when it is written in Prolog. For example, if you write your log files as a series of Prolog **facts**, you can then easily consult them and run queries over them to generate *reports*. Any other format only makes this more complicated.

## Synchronization

The second issue is much more subtle and regards **race conditions** between the threads. For example, in the code you show, there is a critical point in time where *no data* is available at all:

```
loop :-
    read_serial(X),
    check(X),
    retractall(currentvalue(_)),
    currentvalue/1 is not available at this point in time!
    assertz(currentvalue(X)),
    loop.
```

If the fetching thread queries `currentvalue/1` at this critical time where it is not defined, it may *unexpectedly* fail.

For SWI-Prolog, closely read the chapter about [**thread synchronization**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=threadsync) to avoid such issues.

For example, we can implement it as:

```
loop :-
    read_serial(X),
    check(X),
    with_mutex(synch, (retractall(currentvalue(_)),
                       assertz(currentvalue(X)))),
    loop.
```

In the querying thread, you would use `with_mutex(synch, currentvalue(X))` to *fetch* the current value. This ensures that it will not happen during the critical point in time where the old value is already removed, but the new one is not yet asserted.

Note that both the toplevel and also any other thread can query these predicates. To spawn further threads, simply use `thread_create/3` again with different goals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Especially the with_mutex tip. However I am not sure how to open the serial port to use read/1 or read/2 or library pio . I will update my question for more details.

Comment: You probably forgot to emit a newline by the sender? Try appending an "\n".

Comment: I added `Serial.print('\n');` which emitted newlines in the serial monitor.. but the prolog outputs: `?- go('/dev/ttyACM0').
end_of_file
true.` or `?- go('/dev/ttyACM0').
255
true.` so progress but it seems to stop after one read?

Comment: doh ! I didnt write a loop , it works now great! Thank you so much!